# Is there a way to allow a proxy connection to use passed authentication in a public database link?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, database-link

I think the answer to this is no, but I could be wrong.  If nothing else it might be nice for others to be aware of this limitation of proxy connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in Oracle 11.2.0.2 proxy connections cannot use passed authentication in a public database link.  Switch to a private database link with specified authentication.